# Twitter Web service in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, twitter

I want to use twitter web service in my silverlight application but don't know where I can find skd and web service reference for the twitter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using twitter API with silverlight or any .net client app, you cannot just add a service reference to the project. You have to hand code and make direct calls to each feature you require. You should go through the their API wiki [here](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/) and a tutorial [here](http://chris.59north.com/post/SilverTweet-e28093-Building-a-Silverlight-Twitter-client-part-1.aspx).

If you want things done fast, use a library like [tweetsharp](http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/).